# Fonts styled in Google Doc drastically different from displayed iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, google-docs

I have a published Google doc, which looks nice when opened from Google Drive with its fonts, lists, headings, etc.

However, when I embed this published link in an `<iframe>`, it looks hideous. The iframe has constructed many pieces of HTML whose classes do not match the styling of the original document, for example, the following line is 11pt Arial Bold in my doc:

```
<h1 style="display:inline"><span class="c18">Purpose</span></h1>

.c18 {
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  font-size: 24pt; !! WRONG
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 0pt;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 11pt; !! Not working as it should be.
  padding-bottom: 10pt;
  font-family: "Cambria"; !! WRONG, but active
  line-height: 1.1500000000000001;
  orphans: 2;
  widows: 2;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens or how to modify this behavior?

Comment: Are you saying that google is inserting different styles into the embedded doc?

Comment: yes, the `src` attribute that Google Docs gives you for the `iframe` has its own styling imposed when you visit that URL.

Comment: I know with google sheets there are query string parameters that affect how it is embedded. I couldn't find anything similar with docs, though that doesn't mean they don't exist.